# Snoop doesn't detect

Tags: wpf, snoop

I have Windows7 and Visual studio 2008.
I've opened new Wpf Application and run it, and run Snoop and it didn't detect my wpf window.
why ?

I've tried the Refresh button - didn't help.

Comment: What version of snoop are you running?
Are you targeting x64 or x86.

Comment: @hkon - yeee I had an old version of snoop! thanks!!

Answer (score 33):

Try:

- Run Snoop as administrator (right click, "run as administrator");

If it fails:

- Run Snoop and VS 2k8 as administrator

Comment: Looks like you need to run Snoop as admin if you're running VS as admin.

Answer (score 0):

The [Codeplex](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) installers are more up-to-date than the download links on the main site (at least the site that comes up first in search results).

This caused me trouble as well.